# Change color of UISegmentedControl and remove edges programmatically iOS7+

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, uiswitch

It's annoying having the edges of the UISegmentControl look like this when the colour is different:

[image]

Is there a way to remove or hide the colour or reshape the UISegment to mask it?

Second question is how can I change the colour programmatically when switching from on/off/other?

*NOTE: I have used the "answer your own question" option as I couldn't find an answer to removing the colour from the corner edges and solved my problem this way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the colour of UISwitch you can use the following in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
//Custom colour
UIColor * customColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 255/255.0f green: 239/255.0f blue: 54/255.0f alpha: 1.0f];
//sets custom colour tint of selected
[self.yourSwitch setTintColor:customColor];
//sets background colour using default UIColor option
[self.yourSwitch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

This will give the same look as in the question.

To remove the edges use this code in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
//this sets a border with a rounded edge so the
self.yourSwitch.layer.borderWidth = 1.2f;
self.yourSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
```

To have the color change in diffierent positions (ON/OFF/Other), use the following:

```
- (IBAction)yourSwitchSelection:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    if (self.yourSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        UIColor * customColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 255/255.0f green: 112/255.0f blue: 0/255.0f alpha: 1.0f];
        [self.yourSwitch setTintColor:customColor];
    }
    if (self.yourSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

        UIColor * customColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 255/255.0f green: 239/255.0f blue: 54/255.0f alpha: 1.0f];
        [self.yourSwitch setTintColor:customColor];
    }

}
```

It will now look like this when index 0 is selected:

[image]

And like this when index 1 is selected:

[image]